# Android Canvas weird shifting

Tags: java, android, canvas

I have a problem I was trying to solve for almost 2 days. (It ended up by switching to OpenGL :D)
Anyway... I have Canvas and I am trying to do a simple snake game. Just for this problem imagine our snake is made up from 5x5 pixels rectangles, he is leaving the trail (no clearing) and moving to the right from 0, 50 position... here is the code:

```
public class Snake extends AnimationWallpaper {

    @Override
    public Engine onCreateEngine() {
        return new SnakeEngine();
    }

    class SnakeEngine extends AnimationEngine {
        int i = 0;
        Paint paint = new Paint();

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {
            super.onCreate(surfaceHolder);

            // By default we don't get touch events, so enable them.
            setTouchEventsEnabled(true);
        }

        @Override
        public void onSurfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format,
                                     int width, int height) {
            super.onSurfaceChanged(holder, format, width, height);
        }

        @Override
        public void onOffsetsChanged(float xOffset, float yOffset,
                                     float xOffsetStep, float yOffsetStep, int xPixelOffset,
                                     int yPixelOffset) {

            super.onOffsetsChanged(xOffset, yOffset, xOffsetStep, yOffsetStep,
                    xPixelOffset, yPixelOffset);
        }

        @Override
        public Bundle onCommand(String action, int x, int y, int z,
                                Bundle extras, boolean resultRequested) {
            if ("android.wallpaper.tap".equals(action)) {
            }
            return super.onCommand(action, x, y, z, extras, resultRequested);
        }

        @Override
        protected void drawFrame() {
            SurfaceHolder holder = getSurfaceHolder();

            Canvas c = null;
            try {
                c = holder.lockCanvas();
                if (c != null) {
                    draw(c);
                }
            } finally {
                if (c != null)
                    holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
            }
        }

        void draw(Canvas c) {
            //c.save();
            //c.drawColor(0xff000000);

            paint.setAntiAlias(true);

            // paint the fill
            paint.setColor(Color.RED);
            paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
            c.drawRect(i*5, 50, (i+1)*5, 55, paint);

            //c.restore();
        }

        @Override
        protected void iteration() {
            i++;

            super.iteration();
        }

    }

}
```

And here is output:
[image: output]

And that is not all, when it draws its kinda shifting... meaning what you see is shifted to the right side so it doesnt actualy stand in the same place...

If you have any idea why is it behave like that, please tell me!

Answer (score 0):

In canvas, there's a reusability functionality which practically just add new drawings to whatever is in the canvas, hence if you are drawing 1 square at the time, the next time you will have whatever u had before +1, if you don't want that, and you want to fully manipulate every single draw from scratch, just add this line of code before to start drawing

```
canvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT, PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR);
```

It will clear anything you had in the previous state of the canvas, and you can start again drawing whatever you want...

Hope It Helps!

Regards!

Comment: No, I don't want clear, actualy I want the oposite. But it should draw straight line instead of dashed... that is the "shift" what I am talking about. Srsly don't know where is the problem... I've logged the actual variables and they are fine... maybe some DPI problem? dunno...